# How do I swap x-axis and y-axis when using pandas.DataFrame.plot( kind = 'hist' )?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I have my dataframe `df_power` and I want to make a histogram with the value counts of a column `Age` in my dataframe. I have the following code:

```
ages = df_power.Age.value_counts().sort_index()
age_plot = ages.plot(kind = 'hist', legend = True)
age_plot.set_xlabel("Age (Years)")
age_plot.set_ylabel("Count")
```

which gives the following histogram:
[image]

But if I use the default line-graph:

```
age_plot = ages.plot(legend = True)
```

I get a graph that looks like this (which is the correct axis orientation that I am looking for but I want it in a histogram form):
[image]

I cannot find a way to swap the axes and would appreciate any help or solution.

Comment: Mind that `df.value_counts().sort_index().plot(kind = 'hist', ..)` does not make much sense. It's plotting a histogram of already histogrammed values. It thereby tells you that 100 of the age values occur between 0 and 500 times.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you so much, I understand now. So I should be able to plot the histogram of the values directly from the dataframe without having to count them?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I just tried it out and it works perfectly with the desired result! Thanks for the knowledge!